# breathe cannot find C# interface

Tags: doxygen, python-sphinx

I'm trying to use doxygen, breathe and sphinx to generate documentation for a C# library. This is under Windows. The basic directory structure is:

```
docs
    index.rst
    conf.py
    xml
        xml output from doxygen
```

I'm running into the following error when I execute make.bat html:

> C:\Programming\J4JLogging\J4JLogging\docs\index.rst:25: WARNING: doxygeninterface: Cannot find class "IJ4JLoggerConfiguration" in doxygen xml output for project "J4JLogger" from directory: ./xml

Here's the contents of conf.py

```
# import os
# import sys
# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))

project = 'J4JLogger'
copyright = '2019, Mark Olbert'
author = 'Mark Olbert'

extensions = [ "breathe" ]

breathe_projects = {
    "J4JLogger": "./xml"
}

breathe_default_project = "J4JLogger"

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

and here's the contents of index.rst:

```
.. J4JLogger documentation master file, created by
sphinx-quickstart on Tue Jun 11 16:33:34 2019.
You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to J4JLogger's documentation!
=====================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`

Docs
====

.. doxygeninterface:: IJ4JLoggerConfiguration
   :members:
```

The contents of the xml folder created by doxygen looks like this:

[image]

Comment: There are a number of components involved here. Doxygen does not understand rst files so this is probably translated in some way to a format usable by doxygen. To be able to say something more from the doxygen side: 1) What is the input to doxygen. 2) which doxygen version are you using?